# Split string into 3 random-length parts

Tags: php, random, split, substring, explode

I have a string and I want to split it into 3 random-length parts (without caring about string length is the objective) to get 3 strings.

```
$mystring = "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucGhwLm5ldC9tYW51YWwvZW4vZnVuY3Rpb24uc3RyLXNwbGl0LnBocA==";
```

When I tried to use `str_split()`, I always have to manually set the number of character per string.

If I calculate the string length and divide it by 3, sometimes I get non-whole numbers.

```
$len = strlen($mystring);
$len = $len / 3;
$parts = str_split($mystring, $len);
print_r($parts);
```

Comment: Can you just change it to `$len = ceil($len/3);` ? They won't be exactly "random", but it'll avoid any issue with rounding

Comment: Get a random number `n1` less than length-1, get the substring from 0 to `n1`. Then get a random number `n2` less than the remaining length, and get the substring from `0` to `n2` of the remainder as the 2nd part. The 3rd part is the remainder.

Comment: "without caring about the length" can be interpreted as it doesn't matter at all. Thus the first two strings can each be 1 character in length and the last one can be the rest of the string :)

Comment: What does random mean in this instance? Most of the answers below using random give a very biased split of the string (part 1 will average ~50% of the string). Are you expecting a truly random split? If so you need to use a proper partitioning algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you want random then I assume you still don't want 0 length strings.
I use random values between 1 and string length (minus some, to make sure you don't run out of characters).

```
$mystring = "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucGhwLm5ldC9tYW51YWwvZW4vZnVuY3Rpb24uc3RyLXNwbGl0LnBocA==";

$len=strlen($mystring);
$parts[] = substr($mystring, 0, $l[] = rand(1,$len-5));
$parts[] = substr($mystring, $l[0], $l[] = rand(1,$len-$l[0]-3));
$parts[] = substr($mystring, array_sum($l));

print_r($parts);
```

The code grabs parts of the string depending on what the previous random value was.
https://3v4l.org/v4nUF

Comment: Not works well while strlen<5 because of `$len-5` return minus, then `rand(1,-2)`

Comment: I don't see how that is relevant to the question. The input is a hash/base64 and they generally is longer than five characters. If the input in the question had been something else or shorter then my answer would have been different

Comment: @Andreas I am convinced that my answer was flawed to its core.  First I realized that it was not limiting the explosions -- which is a rookie gaff.  Second, exploding on a substring that might exist one or more times in the string will not provide my intended effect/result.  I'll only undelete it if I find a unique, valuable solution.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do it:

```
$mystring = "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucGhwLm5ldC9tYW51YWwvZW4vZnVuY3Rpb24uc3RyLXNwbGl0LnBocA==";

$part3 = substr($mystring, rand(2,(strlen($mystring)-2)));
$mystring = substr($mystring, 0, (strlen($mystring)-strlen($part3)));

$part2 = substr($mystring, rand(1,(strlen($mystring)-1)));
$mystring = substr($mystring, 0, (strlen($mystring)-strlen($part2)));

$part1 = $mystring;

var_dump($part1, $part2, $part3);
```

This code would produce results such as:

```
string(67) "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucGhwLm5ldC9tYW51YWwvZW4vZnVuY3Rpb24uc3RyLXNwbGl0LnB"
string(1) "o"
string(4) "cA=="

string(57) "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucGhwLm5ldC9tYW51YWwvZW4vZnVuY3Rpb24uc3RyL"
string(5) "XNwbG"
string(10) "l0LnBocA=="

string(31) "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucGhwLm5ldC9tYW5"
string(27) "1YWwvZW4vZnVuY3Rpb24uc3RyLX"
string(14) "NwbGl0LnBocA=="

string(5) "aHR0c"
string(23) "HM6Ly93d3cucGhwLm5ldC9t"
string(44) "YW51YWwvZW4vZnVuY3Rpb24uc3RyLXNwbGl0LnBocA=="
```

Answer (score 0):

A more generic solution could look like this:

```
function split_random_parts($string, $part_count) {
    $result = [];
    
    for ($i = 0; $i < $part_count - 1; $i++) {
        // Always leave part_count - i characters remaining so that no empty string gets created
        $len = rand(1, strlen($string) - ($part_count - $i));
        $result[] = substr($string, 0, $len);
        $string = substr($string, $len);
    }
    
    $result[] = $string;
    
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need divide to 3 **without random length**, may you use [str_pad](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) like

```
$str = 'aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cnVuY3Rpb24uc3RyLXNwbGl0LnBocA==';
$divide = 3;
$char = '*'; // that not used in your string

$add = $divide - strlen($str) % $divide;
$total = strlen($str) + $add;

$str = str_pad($str, $total, $char, STR_PAD_LEFT);

//string(48) "**aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cnVuY3Rpb24uc3RyLXNwbGl0LnBocA=="

$result = str_split($str, $total / $divide );

/*array(3) {
  [0]=> string(16) "**aHR0cHM6Ly93d3"
  [1]=> string(16) "cnVuY3Rpb24uc3Ry"
  [2]=> string(16) "LXNwbGl0LnBocA=="
}*/
```

keep in mind that strip `'*'` chars before decode

```
$result = str_replace('*', '', $result);
```

### [Demo](https://3v4l.org/XDlTD)

Comment: This is the correct answer to a different question.  This does not execute the required logic expressed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I mean you just need to round up the result of length  division like:

```
<?php
$mystring = "The any size string ...";
$len=strlen($mystring);
$chunk=ceil($len/3);

$parts = str_split($mystring , $chunk);
print_r($parts);
```

Here the [fiddle](https://phpize.online/?phpses=93073fe8fef29ee88a4403f3c5b02903&sqlses=null&php_version=php7&sql_version=mysql57)

Comment: This is the correct answer to a different question.  This does not execute the required logic expressed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Because your input string contains no whitespace characters, you can use `sscanf()` with `%s` placeholders with explicit substring lengths (for the first two substrings) to explode the string on dynamic points.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sLndj))

```
$mystring = "aHR0cHM6Ly93d3cucGhwLm5ldC9tYW51YWwvZW4vZnVuY3Rpb24uc3RyLXNwbGl0LnBocA==";

$len = strlen($mystring);
$end_of_first = rand(1, $len - 2);
$end_of_middle = rand(1, $len - $end_of_first - 1);

var_export(sscanf($mystring, "%{$end_of_first}s%{$end_of_middle}s%s"));
```

For anyone else who might have whitespaces in their input string, you can replace the `s` with `[^~]` where the `~` should be a character that is guaranteed to not occur in your string.

---

For an approach that accommodates a variable number of segments, a decementing loop seems appropriate.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/ce2VE))

```
$totalSegments = 4;

$segments = [];
while ($totalSegments) {
    --$totalSegments;
    $segmentLength = rand(1, strlen($mystring) - $totalSegments);
    [$segments[], $mystring] = sscanf($mystring, "%{$segmentLength}s%s");
}
var_export($segments);
```